# How do I make the kerning between letters uniform?

Tags: align, kerning

[image: The first line on the right is significantly longer than the two on the bottom despite all three having the same number of letters]

I believe letter I's here are what caused the problem, so how exactly do I force the kerning between letters to be the same in order to make all three lines of the same length?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for a so-called [**typewriter** font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) (**monospaced** font) as opposed to a **proportionally** spaced font ("normal" font). You can use `\ttfamily` (switch) or `\texttt{Text}` (command with argument) for example. An alternative is using a [`verbatim` environment](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatim).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section Title}

Some text in normal font.

\ttfamily\noindent
ABCDEF\\
GHijkL\\
mNloPq

\rmfamily\noindent
Some text in normal font.

\end{document}
```

[image]

For your **next question**, please read and follow this [post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

[image]
*(Taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font.)*

Comment: Thanks mate this is exactly what I was looking for. Also pardon me for the lack of formality. I'm new to the site but I'm will be careful with future posts.

Comment: @ok12345 Good. Then please accept the answer so that the process comes to an end :).